# Mysql count result with zero value

Tags: mysql, count, row, zero

In mysql, I got table "scores" as follow

```
Id  Date                Name        score
1   2011-08-24 00:00:00 sharique    10
2   2011-08-24 00:00:00 joe     11
3   2011-08-24 00:00:00 vijay       5
4   2011-08-25 00:00:00 sharique    0
5   2011-08-25 00:00:00 joe    11
```

Now when I am running query

```
SELECT date,count(id) as count FROM scores where `name` = 'vijay' group by `date`;
```

I am getting result as

```
date                 count
2011-08-24 00:00:00,  1
```

instead of

```
date                 count
2011-08-24 00:00:00,  1
2011-08-25 00:00:00,  0
```

how can i display result with zero count, please?

Comment: It's the expected result. You only have `vijay` once in your dataset..

Comment: it is not the expected result. He wants to show all dates including the days without having `vijay`

Comment: That’s true, I want to display result with zero count, maybe it is expected result for a given query, but my problem is to display count for each day including zero, so that I can say on which day “vijay” did not play or score anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
SELECT s2.date, count(s1.id) as count
FROM (select distinct `date` from scores) s2 
  left join scores s1
    on  s1.`date` = s2.`date`
    and s1.`name` = 'vijay'
group by 1
```

This guarantees a date for everybody for every distinct date in the table

Comment: My thoughts exactly (except typed faster :) )

Comment: It's the other way around: `(select distinct ...) left join scores`

Comment: thanks to all, it is working now... special thanks to @ypercube

Answer (score 0):

It is The Expected Result as You Are Counting the number of rows that matches your where condition.

```
SELECT date,count(id) as count FROM scores where `name` = 'vijay' group by `date`;
```

It selects only one record hence the result of count is 1.

If you want to count all the rows use don't restrict the data by using `Where Clause` e.g:-

```
SELECT date,count(id) as count FROM scores group by `date`;
```

Like wise the following query will return 3 as count..

```
SELECT date,count(id) as count FROM scores where id in (1,2,3) group by `date`;
```